# JS Sum suite of positive / negative based on range

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, array-map

I'm using NodeJS (Javascript) and trying to achieve the following result :

**Input :**

```
let input = [{
        value: 'A',
        gap: 1
    }, {
        value: 'B',
        gap: 2
    }, {
        value: 'C',
        gap: 3
    }, {
        value: 'D',
        gap: -2
    }, {
        value: 'E',
        gap: -3
    }, {
        value: 'F',
        gap: 3
    }, {
        value: 'G',
        gap: 0
    }, {
        value: 'H',
        gap: -1
    }, {
        value: 'I',
        gap: 9
    }];
```

**Expected Result :**

```
let expectedResult = [{
        value: 'A',
        gap: 6
    }, {
        value: 'D',
        gap: -5
    }, {
        value: 'F',
        gap: 3
    }, {
        value: 'H',
        gap: -1
    }, {
        value: 'I',
        gap: 9
    }];
```

The expected result would be the sum of each suite of positives / negatives by capturing the first "value" in each addition.

*Note : The output can either be a change in the original array or building a new one.*

Tried different approaches using array map / reduce / sort but was not satisfied with the result or at least could not achieve exactly what I was looking for.
Can you suggest an optimized solution according to your POV ?
Thanks.

Comment: How do you calculate `gap` (=9) for `value` (="I")?

Comment: Appologies, I forgot to update the input. Please let me know if it's clearer for you.

Comment: Here is my solution: `const res=input.reduce((a,c)=>{
 if(c.gap!==0) {
  let lasta=a[a.length-1];
  if(lasta && (lasta.gap>0) == (c.gap>0))
   lasta.gap+=c.gap;
  else a.push(c);
 }
 return a;}, [] );`. Sorry for the formatting - question was closed.

Comment: And here is an improved one for the case when the first gap is 0: `const res=input.reduce((a,c,i)=>{
 if(!i || c.gap) {
  let lasta=a[a.length-1];
  if(lasta && (!lasta.gap || (lasta.gap>0) == (c.gap>0)))
   lasta.gap+=c.gap;
  else a.push(c);
 }
 return a;}, [] );`

Comment: @cars10m I've added your solution along with my answer. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a new array for `same sign elements` and then map over from reverse order to achieve the desired result.

**1)**

```js
let input = [
  {
    value: "A",
    gap: 1,
  },
  {
    value: "B",
    gap: 2,
  },
  {
    value: "C",
    gap: 3,
  },
  {
    value: "D",
    gap: -2,
  },
  {
    value: "E",
    gap: -3,
  },
  {
    value: "F",
    gap: 3,
  },
  {
    value: "G",
    gap: 0,
  },
  {
    value: "H",
    gap: -1,
  },
  {
    value: "I",
    gap: 9,
  },
];

let lastType = input[0].gap > 0 ? true : false;
const result = input.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      const { value, gap } = curr;

      if ((lastType && gap >= 0) || (!lastType && gap < 0))
        acc[acc.length - 1].push(curr);
      else {
        acc.push([curr]);
        lastType = !lastType;
      }
      return acc;
    },
    [[]]
  )
  .map((arr) => {
    const obj = { value: "", gap: 0 };
    for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      const { value, gap } = arr[i];
      obj["value"] = value;
      obj["gap"] += gap;
    }
    return obj;
  });

console.log(result);
```

**2)**

```js
let input = [
  {
    value: "A",
    gap: 1,
  },
  {
    value: "B",
    gap: 2,
  },
  {
    value: "C",
    gap: 3,
  },
  {
    value: "D",
    gap: -2,
  },
  {
    value: "E",
    gap: -3,
  },
  {
    value: "F",
    gap: 3,
  },
  {
    value: "G",
    gap: 0,
  },
  {
    value: "H",
    gap: -1,
  },
  {
    value: "I",
    gap: 9,
  },
];
const accumulator = [[{ ...input[0], gap: 0 }]];

let lastType = input[0].gap > 0 ? true : false;
const result = input.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const { value, gap } = curr;

    if ((lastType && gap >= 0) || (!lastType && gap < 0)) {
      lastEl = acc[acc.length - 1][0].gap += gap;
    } else {
      acc.push([curr]);
      lastType = !lastType;
    }
    return acc;
  }, accumulator)
  .flat();

console.log(result);
```

**3) Thanks to [cars10m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2610061/cars10m) for the following solution**

```js
let input = [{
    value: "A",
    gap: 1,
  },
  {
    value: "B",
    gap: 2,
  },
  {
    value: "C",
    gap: 3,
  },
  {
    value: "D",
    gap: -2,
  },
  {
    value: "E",
    gap: -3,
  },
  {
    value: "F",
    gap: 3,
  },
  {
    value: "G",
    gap: 0,
  },
  {
    value: "H",
    gap: -1,
  },
  {
    value: "I",
    gap: 9,
  },
];
const res = input.reduce((a, c) => {
  if (c.gap !== 0) {
    let lasta = a[a.length - 1];
    if (lasta && lasta.gap > 0 == c.gap > 0) lasta.gap += c.gap;
    else a.push(c);
  }
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks, you have been helpful despite all the useless negativity coming from the evaluation of my post by the moderators.

Comment: Glad I could help, But others are expecting at least show them what you've tried.